# rtorrent installation errors

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-server

I am getting a error while trying to install rtorrent on my ubuntu server.

```
./configure --with-xmlrpc-c
```

I am able to configure it successfully with above command but i get an error when i try to `make` also when i `make install`

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the dependencies for XMLRPC support satisfied?

Quote from [Using XMLRPC with rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentXMLRPCGuide):

> What you need:

```
*  http://python.ca/scgi/ for Apache, Lighttpd should have this built-in.
*  http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/ 1.00 or later, 1.07 or later for 64bit integer support.
*  rtorrent 0.7.5 or later.
```

Comment: yes i have used this command for installation `apt-get install php5 php5-xmlrpc libapache2-mod-scgi`

Comment: xmlrpc-c is a C/C++, not a Php thing. And  apt-get install <something> installs the latest version from the repository, which can have a lower version than the required by rtorrent.